# Count values less than x and find nearest values to x by multiple groups

Tags: r, count, dplyr

Sample data frame `data`

```
         uid     bas_id dist2mouth type
2020   2019 W3A9101601   2.413629    1
2021   2020 W3A9101601   2.413629    1
2022   2021 W3A9101602   2.413629    1
2023   2022 W3A9101602   3.313893    1
2032   2031 W3A9101602   3.313893    1
2033   2032 W3A9101602   3.313893    1
2034   2033 W3A9101602   3.313893    1
15023 15022 W3A9101601   1.349000    2
15025 15024 W3A9101601   3.880000    2
15026 15025 W3A9101602   3.880000    2
15027 15026 W3A9101602   0.541101    2
16106 17097 W3A9101602   1.349000    2
```

For each row I'd like to calculate how many rows of `type=2` within the same `bas_id` have a lower `dist2mouth`. Effectively how many rows `type=2` are downstream of each row. Store it as `ds_n_type2`. So far I've tried `dplyr`

```
ds <- data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(n_ds = sum(dist2mouth > id[dist2mouth]))
```

I would then like to find the closest row `type=2` to each row `type=1` within the same `bas_id` maybe using `which` in a `for` or `apply` loop. Store it as `closest_uid_type2`. Maybe something like

```
which(abs(x[i:n]-x[i])==min(abs(x[i:n]-x[i])))
```

Happy to clarify

**Edit 2 Desired output amended**

```
         uid     bas_id dist2mouth type ds_n_type2 closest_uid_type2
2020   2019 W3A9101601   2.413629    1  1          15022 
2021   2020 W3A9101601   2.413629    1  1          15022 
2022   2021 W3A9101602   2.413629    1  2          15022 
2023   2022 W3A9101602   3.313893    1  2          15024 
2032   2031 W3A9101602   3.313893    1  2          15024 
2033   2032 W3A9101602   3.313893    1  2          15024 
2034   2033 W3A9101602   3.313893    1  2          15024 
15023 15022 W3A9101601   1.349000    2  -          -
15025 15024 W3A9101601   3.880000    2  -          -
15026 15025 W3A9101602   3.880000    2  -          -
15027 15026 W3A9101602   0.541101    2  -          -
17097 W3A9101602   1.349000    2  -          -
```

Comment: If you show the full desired output corresponding to the example, that'll clarify a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(bas_id) %>%
  mutate(n_ds = match(dist2mouth,sort(dist2mouth))-1) %>%
  mutate(closest_uid=apply(
    sapply(dist2mouth,function(i)abs(i-dist2mouth)),
    2,function(n) uid[which(n==sort(n)[2])])) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Output:

```
  uid dist2mouth bas_id type n_ds closest_uid
1   1         10      1    1    2           4
2   2          5      1    2    0           3
3   3          6      1    1    1           2
4   4         11      1    1    3           1
5   5          3      2    2    0           6
6   6          4      2    1    1           5
```

**Edit:**

This may not be the most elegant, but here's one way to solve the updated question (pending time to refine it):

```
df$ds_n_type2[df$type==1] <- sapply(as.numeric(row.names(df[df$type==1,])), 
                                function(x) sum(as.numeric(df$dist2mouth[x]) > as.numeric(df$dist2mouth[df$bas_id==df$bas_id[x] & df$type==2])))

df$closest_uid_type2[df$type==1] <- sapply(as.numeric(row.names(df[df$type==1,])),
                                       function(x) df$uid[which(df$dist2mouth==df$dist2mouth[df$bas_id==df$bas_id[x] & df$type==2][which.min(abs(c(df$dist2mouth[df$bas_id==df$bas_id[x] & df$type==2])-df$dist2mouth[x]))])[1]])
```

Output:

```
      uid     bas_id dist2mouth type ds_n_type2 closest_uid_type2
 1:  2019 W3A9101601   2.413629    1          1             15022
 2:  2020 W3A9101601   2.413629    1          1             15022
 3:  2021 W3A9101602   2.413629    1          2             15022
 4:  2022 W3A9101602   3.313893    1          2             15024
 5:  2031 W3A9101602   3.313893    1          2             15024
 6:  2032 W3A9101602   3.313893    1          2             15024
 7:  2033 W3A9101602   3.313893    1          2             15024
 8: 15022 W3A9101601   1.349000    2         NA                NA
 9: 15024 W3A9101601   3.880000    2         NA                NA
10: 15025 W3A9101602   3.880000    2         NA                NA
11: 15026 W3A9101602   0.541101    2         NA                NA
12: 17097 W3A9101602   1.349000    2         NA                NA
```

Comment: my dataset has 76 different `bas_id`s and some of the `dist2mouth` will be the same. Does that explain this error?

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `closest_uid` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 6

Also I'm only interested in the number of `type=2` rows  for both the `n_ds` and `closest_uid`

Comment: @user3725599 - Those differences in the data description are important enough to make the previous answer not apply. See the edited solution for an answer based on your real data. Also, note that your original sample output had incorrect math: 2.413629 is closer to 3.380000 than to 1.349000. So the closest_uid_type2 column would have been all 15024 for the sample output. But to make the output more interesting for error testing, I replaced 3.380000 to 3.880000 to get the example output you had posted.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Ryan. I think you forgot a comma. In both lines it should be 
`row.names(df[df$type == 1, ])` Sorry about the considerable changes...

Comment: @user3725599 - Thanks, and you're welcome. These types of questions can be hard to phrase, so that's alright. You're also correct about the comma if you're using a data frame. I typically use data tables which don't require commas in that way, but I should make a note of that in my answer or change to including commas to err on the safe side. Thanks for the note. I've edited in the commas.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to split your data frame and use `purrr:map`

```
library(purrr)
L <- map(split(df, df$bas_id), ~split(.x, .x$type))

# $`1`
# $`1`$`1`
   # uid dist2mouth bas_id type
# 1:   1         10      1    1
# 2:   3          6      1    1
# 3:   4         11      1    1

# $`1`$`2`
   # uid dist2mouth bas_id type
# 1:   2          5      1    2


# $`2`
# $`2`$`1`
   # uid dist2mouth bas_id type
# 1:   6          4      2    1

# $`2`$`2`
   # uid dist2mouth bas_id type
# 1:   5          3      2    2
```

Answer to first Q

```
twolessthanone <- map_dbl(L, ~sum(.x$'2'$dist2mouth < .x$'1'$dist2mouth))

# 1 2 
# 3 1
```

This is a named vector, don't let the extra numbers confuse you

```
str(twolessthanone)

 # Named num [1:2] 3 1
 # - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "1" "2"
```

Answer to 2nd Q

```
nearestonetotwo <- map(L, ~.x$'1'[which.min(abs(.x$'2'$dist2mouth - .x$'1'$dist2mouth)),])

# $`1`
   # uid dist2mouth bas_id type
# 1:   3          6      1    1

# $`2`
   # uid dist2mouth bas_id type
# 1:   6          4      2    1
```